# Can't Get Email from Facebook Login(API Version 2.8)

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, passport-facebook

For my application(Node.js) i'm using passport-facebook and everything works well except that i can't get user email. I found a lot of issues on this subject but for some reason they not fix my problem. I would be really preciate for some help. So my configurations:

app.js

```
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', {scope: 'email'}));

// in scope i tried a different options like ['email'] or ['emails'] and so go on

app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login'
}));
```

passport.js:

```
passport.use('facebook', new FacebookStrategy({
  clientID        : secret.facebook.clientID,
  clientSecret    : secret.facebook.clientSecret,
  callbackURL     : secret.facebook.callback
},
  function(access_token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    console.log(profile) // here i got all profile data except email
    process.nextTick(function() {
      User.findOne({ 'facebook.id' : profile.id }, function(err, user) {
        if (err)
          return done(err);
          if (user) {
            return done(null, user);
          } else {
            var newUser = new User();
            console.log(profile.email) // here i got undefined
            newUser.facebook.id = profile.id;
            newUser.facebook.token = access_token;
            newUser.facebook.firstName = profile.name.givenName;
            newUser.facebook.lastName = profile.name.familyName;
            newUser.facebook.email = profile.email;

            newUser.save((err) => {
              if (err)
                throw err;
              return done(null, newUser);
            });
         } 
      });
    });
}));
```

facebook-secret.js

```
module.exports = {
  facebook: {
    clientID: '****',
    clientSecret: '********',
    callback: '/auth/facebook/callback',
    profileFields: ['id', 'email']
  }
}
```

in UserSchema:

```
facebook: {
    id: String,
    token: String,
    email: String,
    name: String,
  }
```

facebok - settings[image: facebook-settings]

graph - api

[image: graph-api]

Answer (score 1):

in passport.js :

```
passport.use('facebook', new FacebookStrategy({
  clientID        : secret.facebook.clientID,
  clientSecret    : secret.facebook.clientSecret,
  callbackURL     : secret.facebook.callback
},
```

change to:

```
 passport.use('facebook', new FacebookStrategy({
  clientID        : secret.facebook.clientID,
  clientSecret    : secret.facebook.clientSecret,
  callbackURL     : secret.facebook.callback,
  profileFields   : secret.facebook.profileFields
},
```

My profileField : profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'email', 'first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name']

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the scopes in url as param like you used in graph API(?fields=id,email...).

Comment: nope not working(callback stuck and not returning or just transition on another page which not exist and redirect on my default)

Comment: But this part {scope: 'email'} works because i write like this {scope: ['public_profile', 'user_friends', 'email']} and then in Telerik Fiddler catch request HTTP/1.1 302 Found
X-Powered-By: Express
Location: facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=public_profile%2Cuser_friends%2Cemail&client_id=422349 ... I even cant understand that it's problem on my side or some fb configurations.I'm totally stuck.